# How to run code after showDialog is dismissed in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to update the Homepage just after the `showDialog()` is dismissed/disposed? Doesn't seem like it has an `onDispose()` function.

Found another possible Answer : The `WillPopScope` can help detect if the back button is pressed.

The widget that will be used in the `showDialog`, in its build function the widget can be wrapped in `return new WillPopScope(child: ______, onWillPop: _______);` The code can be run in the `onWillPop` function. This can update the Homepage below.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Simply use `await` or `then`. the code in `then` block will be run after the dialog is dismissed.

```
showDialog(
  // Your Dialog Code
).then((val){
  Navigator.pop(_context);
});
```

Comment: If you are using await, you don't need to use .then() .. :)

Comment: good old `onDialogDismissed` callback would still be preferable

Comment: @bobmoff, if we want to return value in the function that call showDialog, still need await

Comment: @bobmoff is right. Just `var valFromDialog = await showDialog()` or `showDialog().then((value) { // do something});`

Comment: I was thinking of a callback also, but I think this is also logical: showDialog, *then* doSomething. Pretty logical

Answer (score 29):

It really depends on the type of updates you want to have.

However, this is a simple example that may help you figure it out.

[image]

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String _homeData = "initial data";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(_homeData),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Show Dialog"),
              onPressed: ()async{
                bool shouldUpdate = await showDialog(
                  context: this.context,
                  child:new AlertDialog(
                    content: new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text("update home"),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
                setState(() {
                  shouldUpdate ? this._homeData = "updated" : null;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the same result if the back button is pressed on the phone? If the user clicks either of the buttons.

Comment: The back button on the phone will return null, hence 
`setState((){
                 shouldUpdate==true||shouldUpdate==null?this._homeData = "updated":null;
               });`

Comment: Actually this will result in also updating the home if user dismiss the modal by clicking outside of it too

Comment: I think your issue is now more of UX issue, I do not know your use case for having the user dismiss the dialog and still get data updated, updating data should be controlled by triggering a meaningful action unlike dismissing

Comment: Use case: I am trying out a Flutter lib 'SpriteWidget'. I have a main 'node' to which other 'sprites/nodes' are attached. I am showing a new arrangement/layout of the attached nodes in a 'showDialog' and the visible backpage is blank as I want it . So when I dismiss this dialog, with either a button or the phone button, I want to run code to reassemble the backpage layout. Thank you.

Comment: Found as answer, I've added it to the question above.

Answer (score 8):

If you have made another StatefulWidget for your DialogBox and onDissmissed, you want to call some function in the "dialog calling widget". You can this snippet.

```
await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => MenuBox(),
);
print("now closed");
```

Answer (score 7):

Mobile apps typically reveal their contents via full-screen elements called "screens" or "pages". In Flutter these elements are called routes and they're managed by a **Navigator** widget. The navigator manages a stack of Route objects and provides methods for managing the stack, like `Navigator.push` and `Navigator.pop`.

```
showDialog(
            context: context,
            child: new AlertDialog(
                title: const Text("Your Title"),
                content: const Text(
                  ...
                   Your Message
                  ...),
                actions: [
                new FlatButton(
                  child: const Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        );
```

You can check [Official Document](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

Comment: Will it update if the back button is pressed on the phone and not the button on the dialog, to dismiss the dialog?

Comment: Is it possible to have a page behave as a dialog. That is - (1) The page  is not full screen, the page size can be controlled and - (2) The backpage is visible from the sides of the overlaid page? so I can use Navigator.pushnamed. Thank you.

Comment: Found as answer, I've added it to the question above.

Answer (score 5):

When tapping outside the dialog the return is null, so I expect a potential null and check for null, which is then false.

```
onPressed: () async {
bool? result = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Select Entity'),
      content: setupAlertDialogContainer(),
    );
  },
);
if (result ?? false) {
  doWhatYouNeedTo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use;
`.whenComplete(funcName/*not funcName() !*/);`
after the `showDialog()`

```
funcName() {
//Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Noticed a couple of the above answers were a bit out of date due to the "child" construct used with the AlertDialog object being deprecated now.

Here is what I use now instead for a blocking alert dialog:

```
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              // return object of type Dialog
              return AlertDialog(
                title: new Text("Conversation Request"),
                content:
                    new Text("Have a conversation with this person"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text("Accept"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      performAccept();
                    },
                  ),
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text("Ignore"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      performIgnore();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches.

1. Use `async-await`

   ```
   bool shouldUpdate = await showDialog<bool>(...);
   if (shouldUpdate) {
     setState(() {
       // we should update the UI
     });
   }
   ```
2. Use `then`

   ```
   showDialog<bool>(...).then((shouldUpdate) {
     if (shouldUpdate) {
       setState(() {
         // we should update the UI
       });
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code below. It will invoke onDismiss and onShow dialog.

```
   void baseDialog(
        {required Widget content,
        required BuildContext context,
        required Function onDialogShow,
        required Function onDialogDismiss,
        bool barrierDismissible = true}) async {
      onDialogShow.call();
    
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
        builder: (_) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(12),
              ),
            ),
            content: Material(color: Colors.white, child: content),
          );
        },
      );
      onDialogDismiss.call();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used Bloc state management to handle this.
The idea is:

```
//On Dialog
clickOKAction: () => blocCubit.emitOKActionState()
...

//On the bloc file
fun emitOKActionState(){
   emit(OKActionState());
}

//On Widget
listener: (context, state) async {
   if(state is OKActionState) {
        // HANDLE YOUR ACTION HERE
   }
}
```

Because after showing Dialog, the current widget will be disposed. So you can not use anything related to `context` for eg, because it's unmounted. This may help solve error like:

> This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct)